# SQL selecting where A equals both B and C

Tags: sql, database

```
name | course
Jay | LAWS0001
Mark | LAWS0002
Sam | LAWS0002
Alice | LAWS0001
Ryan | LAWS0001
Ryan | LAWS0002
```

Hey guys, I've got this database and I want to only select the names that take both 'LAWS0001' and 'LAWS0002'. So from this example, it should select 'Ryan' because he's the only person to take both courses.
I tried IN operator:

```
SELECT name
FROM student
WHERE course IN ('LAWS0001', 'LAWS0002')
```

but this takes everyone because everyone is taking either of the courses.

Is there an operator for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your existing query, using a `GROUP BY` clause to `COUNT` the number of distinct courses each student is taking in the set `('LAWS0001', 'LAWS0002')` and only selecting those students where the count is 2:

```
SELECT name
FROM student
WHERE course IN ('LAWS0001', 'LAWS0002')
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT course) = 2
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac8a9/1)